# How to add an index to each array in a 2d array

Tags: javascript, arrays

### What I want to do

This is a given array:

```js
const input = [
  [true, 'a', 'aa', 'aaa'],
  [false, 'b', 'bb', 'bbb'],
  [true, 'c', 'cc', 'ccc']
];
```

This is an output that I want:

```js
const result = [
  [0, true, 'a', 'aa', 'aaa'],
  [2, true, 'c', 'cc', 'ccc']
];
```

- Only arrays with `true` at the beginning of each array
- Add a number to each array. `0` and `2` are indexes of `input`

### Issue

I've tried to add indexes before using `.filter()` to filter out arrays that don't have `true`. But it seems to return the length of each array.

```js
const result = input.map((arr, i) => arr.unshift(i));
console.log(result);

// Actual result: 
// [5, 5, 5]

// What I expected:  
// [
//   [0, true, 'a', 'aa', 'aaa'],
//   [1, false, 'b', 'bb', 'bbb'],
//   [2, true, 'c', 'cc', 'ccc']
// ];
```

How should I fix the problem?
Here is my whole code

```js
const input = [
  [true, 'a', 'aa', 'aaa'],
  [false, 'b', 'bb', 'bbb'],
  [true, 'c', 'cc', 'ccc']
];

const result = input.map((arr, i) => arr.unshift(i)).filter(arr => arr[1]);
console.log(result); // []
```

Someone has closed my question because of [duplicated]. But I don't understand the post/question's answer.
Could anyone tell me not only the cause but also the specific solution?

Comment: [`unshift`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) returns the new length. You want `const result = input.map((arr, i) => [ i, ...arr ]).filter(arr => arr[1]);` or `const result = input.map((arr, i) => { arr.unshift(i); return arr; }).filter(arr => arr[1]);` or `input.forEach((arr, i) => arr.unshift(i)); const result = input.filter(arr => arr[1]);`. Familiarize yourself with the [arrow function syntax](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). `(arr, i) => arr.unshift(i)` will _return the length_.

Comment: _“Could anyone tell me not only the cause but also the specific solution?”_ — What’s unclear about my previous comment or the answer provided below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a flat mapping and return either a new array or an empty array.

```js
const
    input = [[true, 'a', 'aa', 'aaa'], [false, 'b', 'bb', 'bbb'], [true, 'c', 'cc', 'ccc']],
    result = input.flatMap((a, i) => a[0] ? [[i, ...a]] : []);

console.log(result);
```